# determine cutoff for independant variable based on outcome

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

I have very limited understanding of statistics so have failed to find the correct question to ask, let alone the answer.

I have put multiple samples through a series of experiments where for each experiment a variable "reads" increases. For each experiment the test can pass (seen) or fail (missed).

This has left me with a count of seen and missed for each read which I have plotted in a stacked histogram (preliminary data):

[image]

I would like to determine a cut off for reads where, with a given confidence level, we can say that we wouldn't miss anything. From the above results looks like could say with 5 or more reads we would not miss anything, but I need to say that with an associated confidence value. eg with 5 reads or more would not miss 95% of samples, or with 10 reads would not miss 99% of samples.

What test do I need?
Thanks.

UPDATE:
The way the samples were run across the series had a random element to it, so the counts (Y axis) are not equal across the X axis.

Therefore, I think I should count this as a proportion

I can't determine FP (I can't rule them out) so I can't plot a ROC curve, but could I plot the recall/FNR (I realise they are the inverse of each other):

[image]

I guess as per [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Curves_in_ROC_space) I was hoping to find two normally distributed populations and I could calculate the confidence from the number of SD from the mean of the FNR at my X cutoff value

Comment: I think something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Curves_in_ROC_space) will help me answer where the cut off should be. However I can't determine the number of false positives (I can't rule out anything "seen" being real). I guess I can plot the FN and TP, set my cutoff on the X axis and work out the confidence value using the FN curve?